# How to get the first line of an input text file, while deleting that line from the text file

Tags: text-processing

How can I get the first line of an input text file, while deleting that line from the text file?

If I had a text file `/myPathToTheFile.txt` like this

```
► put returns between paragraphs
► for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
► _italic_ or **bold**
```

I'd like to get this line as an output

```
► put returns between paragraphs
```

and my text file should be now like this

```
► for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
► _italic_ or **bold*
```

Comment: Note that the cost of this operation is proportional to the file size. So if the file is big and you do this often, it will be very slow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
ex -s /myPathToTheFile.txt <<\EX
1p
1d
wq
EX
```

or

```
ex -s /myPathToTheFile.txt <<< 1p$'\n'1d$'\n'wq
```

or, less typing:

```
ed -s /myPathToTheFile.txt <<< $'1\nd\nwq'
```

Comment: Wow, nice use of ed...!

Answer (score 10):

At least with GNU sed:

```
$ cat file
► put returns between paragraphs
► for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
► _italic_ or **bold**

$ sed -i '1{
w /dev/stdout
d}' file
► put returns between paragraphs

$ cat file
► for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
► _italic_ or **bold**
```

With GNU sed it can be written as a one-liner

```
sed -i -e '1 {w /dev/stdout' -e 'd}' file
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are asking for a shell script, this will do what you requested:

```
NAME=$1
head -n 1 $NAME
sed -i '1d' $NAME
```

Answer (score 5):

```
sed -ne '1p' -e '1!s/^//w temp_file' yourfile && mv temp_file yourfile
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `head` , `tail` and `mv`:

Display the first line:

```
head -1 myPathToTheFile.txt
```

Keeping the last (`+2`) lines:

```
tail -n +2 myPathToTheFile.txt > file.tmp && mv file.tmp myPathToTheFile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using file descriptors and a little bit of `python`

```
{
    { 
    head -n1 >&3; 
    3>&- tail -n +1;
    3>&- python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.truncate(sys.stdout.tell())';
    }<file 1<>file
} 3>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using head and tail. File is target.txt

```
head -1 target.txt && tail -n+2 target.txt > tmp
mv tmp target.txt && rm tmp
```

Note: Ensure there is no existing file tmp in the current folder, else it'll be removed.

Explanation:

- "head -1" selects the first line
- "tail -n+2 target.txt > tmp" selects all lines from 2nd onwards( including) and puts them in tmp
- mv overwrites the original file with tmp
- rm tmp will remove the tmp file thus created